# Webdriver doesn't find any elements by id or class NoSuchElementException

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get data from inside a div of a public website. 
The Selenium WebDriver doesn't seem to find any elements. I tried to find elements with id and class even with a XPath but still didn't find anything.
I can see the html page code when looking at PageSource, this confirms the driver works. What am I doing wrong here? Selenium V2.53.1 // IEDriverServer Win32 v2.53.1

My code:

```
    IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver("C:\\Program Files\\SeleniumWebPagetester");
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("D:\\test.html");
    await Task.Delay(30000);
    var src = driver.PageSource; //shows the html page -> works
    var ds = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//html//body")); //NoSuchElementException
    var test = driver.FindElement(By.Id("aspnetForm")); //An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
    var testy = driver.FindElement(By.Id("aspnetForm"), 30); //'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException'
    var tst = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"lx-home\"]"), 30); //'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException'
    driver.Quit();
```

Simple HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="return false;">
         <section id="lx-home" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
          <div class="bigbanner">
            <div class="splash mc">
              <div class="bighead crb">LEAD DELIVERY MADE EASY</div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </section>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Side note, my XPath works perfect with HtmlWeb:

```
    string Url = "D:\\test.html";
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
    var element = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"lx-home\"]"); //WORKS
```

Comment: The code looks ok to me. Can you try an explicit wait after "GoToUrl" step and also if you can read the div element? Want to check if webdriver is having issues with just the form itself or all elements.

Comment: Also, do mention the IE and driver versions

Comment: @Sid I updated the code for you, added a wait and a xpath to the body. And I even removed the from on the html page, no luck

Comment: Is there element exists inside any frame/iframe??

Comment: The general factors that cause such issues are:
1. Mismatch of browser and driver versions. Not all driver versions work on all browser versions
2. Driver doesnt realize the page refreshed -Page wait
3. Element is overlapped by some other element - Element is not visible or similar
4. Not selecting the frame/iframe - Element doesnt get searched in the right section of page

try: var clss  = driver.FindElement(By.Class("bigbanner"), 30); and let us know if the element was found.

Comment: It also fails after trying By.ClassName("bigbanner"). Someone else told you can't use local links. I changed URL to google.com and its stuck now on Page source. This tells me the IE driver isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems IE parses the local file in different way, so you cannot access DOM. Here are your options:

1. Use Chrome instead of IE
2. Keep using IE, move the file to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` then change your code to open URL instead of localfile: `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/test.html");`

Comment: Thanks! Using Chrome, hosted html file and moving the driver out of program files did the trick.